# Automatically check textbox length c#

Tags: c#, automation

For a project at school, I use an RFID reader to read a code. The RFID reader is presented to my pc as an keyboard.

What the program should do is scan a code, get some data from the database and move on. What I can do, is scan a code and then click on a button to search for the code. But this is not really what I want.

What I want is that my c# program automatically searches the database when it notes that there are 8 characters entered (that is the code length on the card) and then returns me the data.

I couldn't really find anything on google, so I was wondering if somebody knows how to accomplish this.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: TextBox change event?

Comment: @AlexK. It think so, really don't know how to accomplish it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `TextChanged` event.

Write the method:

```
protected void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox1.Text.Length >= 8)
    {
        // do things
    }
}
```

Then add it as a listener:

```
textBox1.TextChanged += this.TextBox1_TextChanged;
```

(If you're using the Visual Studio designer you can select the `TextBox`, go to the Properties window, click the Events button, and double click the `TextChanged` event to automatically create and add the method)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the idea to use a timer. Maybe not the best solution but it works for now.

On the form1_load I start a timer and in the event code of the timer I use an if-statement to check the length of a textbox. When it is 8, I stop the timer and display a message.

The code where I start the Timer:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();

    }
```

The code where I execute the code in the event handler:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbScan.Text.Length == 8)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("8 tekens zijn ingevoerd!");
        }

    }
```

But also thanks for your answers and comments! ;)